# Automatic connection from LSASS to different IPs. Is this the usual behavior?

Tags: windows, firewalls, known-vulnerabilities

I'm using Windows 7 and Firefox 22, connecting through a regular residential wifi router.

In the last month, I've noticed that when I connect to the internet once in a while my firewall indicates that lsass wants to connect to different IPs. 
example:

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\LSASS.EXE
Local Security Authority Process
Remote IP: 72.21.91.29
Remote Port: 80
```

I'm not sure if the following is related but since the same time ago, when I connect to the internet, svhost tries to connect to port 80 to multiple certificate website like DigiCert etc.

After trying to search on Google I couldn't find a reason why is connecting to any IP and if that could be something to worry about and investigate a bit more. I haven't found anything about the second situation for this same context (pc, I am not using remote desktop neither I have the functionality enabled, it happens or just after connecting or surfing the web, this is a NEW behavior. I have two wifi to connect. One is shared with 2 more persons but none of the pcs are sharing or in a family group, the other wifi is used only by me and still, the same firewall messages show up). My first guess is that a Windows update for increased security for ipv6 (compared to the one I had) was installed?

Is this clear indication of a spyware or trojan horse or is just the usual behavior of these processes?

Comment: Perhaps check it's checksum against the list at the bottom of http://speedutilities.com/process/lsass.exe.htm (courtesy of wikipedia)

Comment: The name [ocsp.digicert.com resolves](https://archive.is/GRF4O) to this IP [via CDN](https://archive.is/4pGsM). There is a related thread on a Firefox Google Group: 2015-06-28, [*Firefox automatic callouts at startup*](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.support.firefox/_azeJw7PahU). Reason for callout is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

This is a normal part of certificate validation or revocation list update using the OCSP protocol. 
Enjoy reading:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee619730(v=ws.10).aspx
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol

Comment: Do you mean OCSP, Online Certificate Status Protocol? OSCP, Offensive Security Certified Professional is something else. ;)